# Print recordset if value exists in array

Tags: arrays, excel, ado, vba

New to vb and am struggling with returning data from my recordset if variable equals a value in my array.

I think what I've done so far is correct but having trouble with the final bit. I need to script something to say "if value from range equals a value in my array then print the recordset".

I hope someone can help. I'm also new to vb so any suggestions on how to improve my code would be great. Thanks in advance!! Brian

```
        Sub FindCardOrdersv2()

        ' Initialize variables.
        Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
        Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
        Dim provStr As String
        Dim intMaxCol As Integer
        Dim intMaxRow As Integer
        Dim rsFilter As Range
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim rng As Variant
        Dim payid(1 To 10) As String
        Dim tw As ThisWorkbook

        Workbooks("cleanse.xlsm").Activate
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

        ' Create new instances
        Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset


        ' sql query
        sql = "SELECT TOP 100 t.tri_transactionidcode," _
              & "SUBSTRING(t.tri_reference, 1, 9) AS merchantref," _
              & "t.tri_additionalreferencenumber, t.CreatedOn, t.tri_amount, ISNULL(t.tri_paymenttransactiontypeidName, 'Online')" _
              & " FROM dbo.tri_onlinepayment t INNER JOIN dbo.tri_transaction tr ON tr.tri_onlinepaymentid = t.tri_onlinepaymentId" _
              & " WHERE t.tri_transactionresult = 9"

        ' Specify the OLE DB provider.
        cn.Provider = "sqloledb"

        ' Specify connection string on Open method.
        cn.Open "Data Source=IFL-SQL11;Database=IFL_MSCRM;Trusted_Connection=yes;Integrated Security=SSPI"



        ' Assign active connection to recordset
        Set rs.ActiveConnection = cn
        'intMaxCol = rs.Fields.Count

        ' Define cursors and open sql
        With rs
            .CursorLocation = adUseClient
            .CursorType = adOpenStatic
            .LockType = adLockReadOnly
            .Open sql
        End With

        For i = 1 To 3
            payid(i) = rs.Fields.Item(0)
            Debug.Print rs(0)
            Debug.Print rs(1)
            Debug.Print rs(3)
            rs.MoveNext
        Next i

        'rsFilter = Range("A1:A10")



        For Each rsFilter In Range("A1:A10").Cells
            If rsFilter.Value = payid Then
            Debug.Print rs(1)
            rs.MoveNext
            End If
        Next

        'If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
        '   With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        '   .Range("B1:B2").CopyFromRecordset rs
        '   End With
        'End If


        rs.Close
        cn.Close

        Set rs = Nothing
        Set cn = Nothing
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an extra for loop inside to compare every value in the range to the array values

```
For Each rsFilter In Range("A1:A10").Cells
   For i=1 To 3
      If rsFilter.Value = payid(i) Then
        Debug.Print rs(1)
        rs.MoveNext
      End If   
   Next i    
Next
```

Comment: For Each rsFilter In Range("A1:A10").Cells
    For i = 1 To rsFilter.Cells.Count
    Do While Not (rs.BOF And rs.EOF)
        If rsFilter.Value = payid(i) Then
               Debug.Print rsFilter.Value
               Debug.Print rsFilter.Offset(0, 1).Value
        Else: Debug.Print errmsg & " " & rsFilter.Value
        End If
                rs.MoveNext
 
    Loop
    Next i
Exit For
Next
  I'm trying to add a EOF and BOF into the loop too but not sure where to place it. Still getting and error at rs.movenext. Error reads "BOF or EOF is true". Can you point me in the right direction please?

Comment: update the code with the changes you made and I can look at it!

Comment: Hi Thinkingcap, I've progressed from here thanks. Thanks for answering my query :)